# save highscore for each level of game in ios

Tags: ios, math, multi-level

I am new in iOS development and developing a Maths game in which i have 3 levels Easy, Normal and Hard. I want to save high-score programatically for each level but don't know how?

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:@"highScore"]<[SingletonClass sharedSingleton].Score){

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:[SingletonClass sharedSingleton].Score forKey:@"highScore"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
```

I am using this code for saving highscore. but this code saves same highscore for each level.

Comment: why not use Game Center for manage score and achievement its being easy to use and no need to handle using NSUserDefault.

Answer (score 1):

You can use three separate keys for store `highScore` - `MGHighScoreEasy`, `MGHighScoreNormal` and `MGHighScoreHard`,

```
if(gameMode == MGGameModeEasy) {

  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:[SingletonClass sharedSingleton].Score forKey:@"MGHighScoreEasy"];
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
} else if (....) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more a question about how you structure your code/data than how you save it. Given that the high scores are an attribute of the player I would and an NSDictionary property to your user class (guessing that's the singlton) that can store all the high scores.

For example:

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"easy", @"medium", @"hard", nil];
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"value1", @"value2", @"value3", nil]; 
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects 
                                                   forKeys:keys];
```

Now you can store this NSDictionary in NSUserDefaults and when you retrieve it you have all scores.

For example:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dictionary forKey:@"highScores"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: Thanks, it didnt came into my mind to use dictionary and arrays. thanks once again

Comment: @Mikael- i think it will help me.

Comment: @MSwapnil it's the most efficient way I think :)

Answer (score 0):

there is two way to store game score to creating `Database` and storing score card array to `NSUserDefault`.

To store score card array in `NSUserDefault`.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:arrayHighScore  forKey:@"highScore"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:arrayMiddiumScore  forKey:@"MediaumScore"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:arrayEasyScore  forKey:@"EasyScore"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
```

Comment: One `arrayEasyScore` will be saved since you are using the same key for all.

Comment: Actually i left to change key.:)

Answer (score 0):

Using NSUserDefaults to save score would make you game easily hackable.

You can use NSKeyedArchiver to save your data to a file

```
-(void)saveState {


    NSLog(@"Saving state");

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *statePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:someFileName];

    NSMutableData *appData;
    NSKeyedArchiver *encoder;
    appData = [NSMutableData data];
    encoder = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:appData];
     // SaveData using [encoder encodeObject:(id)object forkey(NSString *)key]
    [encoder encodeObject:someUserObject forKey:@"someUserKey"];
    [encoder encodeInteger:someUserscore forKey:@"someUserScoreKey"];


    // Finish encoding and write the contents of gameData to file
    [encoder finishEncoding];
    [appData writeToFile:statePath atomically:YES];


}
```

You can then load the data back with file like so

```
-(void)loadState
{
    NSLog(@"Loading state");

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *statePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:someFileName];

    NSData *appData;
    NSKeyedUnarchiver *decoder;

    appData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:statePath];
    if (appData)
    {
        NSLog (@"file Loaded");
        decoder = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:appData];
        // set data here using [decoder decodeObject for key...
        someUserObject = [decoder decodeIntegerForKey:@"someUserKey"];
        someUserScore = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"someUserScoreKey"];

    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"No saved data available or incorrect file name");
    }

}
```

Any Custom classes that you encode/decode you need to make sure they conform to NSCoding.